# Unable to connect instances of docker-machine to pull docker images running behind a corporate proxy

Tags: docker, boot2docker, docker-machine

I'm trying to configure docker swarm mode using docker-machine. I have set up a cluster of 4 nodes connected to each other. However, I'm not able to connect the instances created by docker-machine to outside world that is running behind a corporate proxy.

Answer (score 0):

When you create your boot2docker machines, you need to make sure you have set your corporate proxy:

```
docker-machine create -d virtualbox \
    --engine-env HTTP_PROXY=http://example.com:8080 \
    --engine-env HTTPS_PROXY=https://example.com:8080 \
    --engine-env NO_PROXY=example2.com \
    default
```